# git get only list of the last i.e. 2 commit

Tags: git

I develope on Windows at home and send my changes to the customer. Customer do not want to have any SCM installed, so I need to send files I've changed from last iteration.
Currently I'm using Subversion with some kind of the automation by self-written batch, that is a mix of windows and GNU/unix utilities. The script looks into the given revisions, list what files are changed, removes duplication and get at the end a file of list.

```
@echo off
if (%3) == () goto usage
set TO_REVISION=HEAD
set PUSHNAME=%3-%1

svn log -v -q -r %2 %3 |  sed "s/^[ ^t]*[AM] \/[[:alnum:]_]*\/[[:alnum:]_]*\/\(.*\.[[:alnum:]_]*\)/tar --append --file=%PUSHNAME%.tar \1/" | sed "s/ (.*//g" | sort | uniq | grep -v "config.xml" >> %PUSHNAME%.bat
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto error
echo bzip2 %PUSHNAME%.tar>> %PUSHNAME%.bat
echo :: SVN REVISIONS :: %2>> %PUSHNAME%.bat
echo ... %PUSHNAME%.bat generated.
goto done

:usage
echo USAGE: %~nx0 push-file-name from[:to]-revision relative-or-absolute-path
echo See svn log -v -q -r [REV] to view repository log.
goto done

:error
echo ERROR! Check (if exists) output file %PUSHNAME%.bat
goto done

:done
```

The batch is not perfect but for me is OK.
Now i decide to move to the Git. I've converted the subversion repository to the Git repo. But show stopper to me I cannot find the replace command for svn -v -q -r log in Git manual :-( 
I'm sure it should be, but after a days of searching I'd like to ask about help more experienced Git-Gurus.

Thank in advance for your minutes spent for my problem,

Oleg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're trying to get a list of files changed since some commit:

```
git diff-index <commit> --name-only
```

Will list all files changed since <commit> and only their names.

`--name-only` will save you trouble of sed'ing the name of files.
Using `--name-status` instead gets you more familiar looking

```
A   debian/control 
M   debian/rules
```

output.

Answer (score 0):

```
git show HEAD HEAD^
```

This will show the last two commits of the current branch. For more options, see `git show --help`

Comment: `HEAD^` refers to parent of `HEAD`

Comment: git --version => git version 1.7.2.3. If I try C:\dev\pim>git show HEAD HEAD^ I'm getting (two times Enter key) (German Mehr is More)Mehr?
Mehr?
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD
': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: @oleg: Do `git branch`. It will show which branch is the current (one with the asterisk). Then replace `HEAD` with `<current branch>`. Anyways, `HEAD` should work. what does `cat .git/HEAD` output?

Comment: C:\dev\reckitt\srcgit\pim2>git branch
  log4net
* master
  production

C:\dev\reckitt\srcgit\pim2>git show master master^
Mehr?
Mehr?
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master
': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

C:\dev\reckitt\srcgit\pim2>cat .git/HEAD
ref: refs/heads/master 
Though, I guess this is a clutter on my workstation. I'm using different installation of UnxUtil / Msysgit and may be it call some wrong...

Comment: @oleg: `HEAD~2` is same as `HEAD^^` or grandparent of `HEAD` commit.

Comment: indeed, git show HEAD^^ does work, but git show HEAD^ requires some more input...